# Oracle: join local index to global index results in error?

Tags: database, oracle

Suppose you have two partitioned tables:

```
table1:
    - id (primary key = global index)
    - created (timestamp of creation)

table2:
    - id (primary key = global index)
    - t1_id (foreign key to table1.id, a local index was created for this field)
```

The partitioning is done on table1.created and table2 is partitioned by reference on table2.t1_id.

Now if I run this query:

```
select * from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.id=t2.t1_id
```

I get the ever awesome error: ORA-03113

I do not have access to the actual server running the oracle instance so I can't check the alert logs. Google turned up nothing useful so after some fiddling I thought that maybe the local index was the problem. I tried adding the necessary clauses to limit the range of partitions that should be targeted to no avail.

I replaced the local index on table2.t1_id with a global index and the query works.

Now my question: is this a feature/bug? Or a logical consequence of how local indexes work? Is it some other problem entirely which I accidently fixed by recreating the index?

Oracle version: 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit

Comment: Yes, there was a bug `10188727`, if I'm not mistaken. It fixed in the 11.2.0.3 and up releases.